# What does canonical extension mean?

Tags: machine-learning

*Density-reachability is a canonical extension of direct density-reachability.*
What is meant by canonical extension?

Source: A Density-Based Algorithm for Discovering Clusters in Large Spatial Databases with Noise https://www.aaai.org/Papers/KDD/1996/KDD96-037.pdf

Comment: Could you give the source of the quote (with hyperlink if possible)?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I added the title and a direct link to the paper where it was used

Answer (score 2):

The term 'extension' could generally be interpreted in mathematical sense<sup>1</sup> as an **enlargement of the domain of a pre-existing function.**

In your case, assume *Density-reachability* could be described as a process $d\colon A \rightarrow B$ mapping inputs from domain $A$ to output in domain $B$. An enlargement of domain could be viewed as another map $e\colon A \rightarrow A'$ which maps where the old inputs in $A$ could be thought of as special cases in subset of $A'$ that is the image of map $e$.

An extension then could be described as any map $x\colon A' \rightarrow B$ which statisfy
$$x \circ e = d$$
There could be many such $x$, so picking extension is a choice. The above equation basically expresses that

> If I pick $a \in A$ from the old domain, translate it to the new domain as $e(a)$, then use this new tool $x$ which could be thought of as an extension of old tool $d$ along the translation $e$, then the final result must agree with just using the old tool $d$ to begin with.

or
$$x \circ e(a) = d(a)\qquad; \forall a \in A$$

The term 'canonical' simply implies that the choice of extension is the obvious, natural one of the situation.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>At least from the perspective of category theory.</sub>